# Best practice boolean logic multiple not equal to

Tags: c#, sql, boolean, equality

When writing a boolean statement with multiple 'not equal to' clauses I believe there are two potential syntaxes for achieving this, both of which are functionally equivalent. c# example:

1.

```
x != 1 && y != 1
```

2.

```
!(x == 1 || y == 1)
```

For the sake of being consistent and deciding on a best practice, are there any clear advantages/disadvantages to either?

Thanks

Comment: `advantages/disadvantages` The readability.

Comment: Write them as you say them. Can be different in different contexts ;-)

Comment: I thought in the back of my mind the optimzation kicks in and says in the first one if x==1 then it aborts checking if y!=1 because it failed at the first hurdle..

Comment: @BugFinder that's true, it kicks, but it kicks in both of cases mentioned in question, so still no difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same indeed, the only difference is the readability. Usually I see the first option more often in code and I prefer this one (for me it's more clear that you don't want them to be equal to something). However, that's a personal preference. If you want you can go with the second one, but just make sure you are consistent throughout your project to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, these two forms are completely equal according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

You should just decide what makes more sense according to your problem's nature, and what will be easier for other programmers to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice for your question, your example is simple Boolean algebra task, changing logical conjunction with logical disjunction expression.
In real life, in application development especially in team projects, developers use predefined conventions, for example if expression can be modified, but it becomes hard readable, they use the syntax which is most suitable for real conditional expression, if condition sounds like "if not A and not B" they wrote !A && !B.
  On the other hand, if there is critical algorithm with sensibility to performance, you should remember about rule of logical expressions shortest execution way. For example, in мost progaramming languages, in your example the expression 
`!(x == 1 || y == 1)` will always calculate operators `x == 1` and `y == 1`, vs the `x != 1 && y != 1` , there, if `x != 1` satisfies the condition, then the `y != 1` won't be calculated.

Comment: Your sentence about "will always calculate operators x == 1 and y == 1" is not true - if `x == 1` evaluates to true - `y == 1` condition will not be evaluated, exactly the same way as with `&&` operator.

Comment: you are right, forget to mention about it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the two examples you've provided. Both of them are fine and it all boils down to readability and preference. If you work in a team you should follow a team standard to and not over-complicate code. This ensures that there is a constant and everyone is able to easily read and understand the logic. which boosts productivity and speeds up debugging.

If you're working on a personal project you can do whatever you like.